# Does the prefix "pre" connote negative meanings? Examples: "Presage" vs "sage", "pretext" and "preclude"

Tags: etymology, connotation, latin, prefixes

I came across the word "presage" through the *Vocabulary Builder* as below

> **presage** *(v.)* presij
>   **to indicate something (usually bad) is about to happen.**
>   *The sudden loss of jobs **presaged** an economic downturn.*
>   The Latin word *ōmen* is thought to be the origin for *presage*. *Presage* can also be a noun, describing an incident or event that presages something.

And I am familiar with the word "sage" as an adjective. *Merriam-Webster Unabridged* says,

> **a**:  eminent in wisdom:  wise through reflection and experience:  prudent and philosophic in judgment and views
>   *the wise reasoning of a certain sage magistrate* — George Berkeley
>
> **b** [*archaic*]:  grave, solemn
>   *among the sage and somber figures that would put his unsophisticated cheerfulness to shame* — Nathaniel Hawthorne
>
> **2**: proceeding from or characterized by wisdom, prudence, and good judgment
>   *providing sage guidance to non-ponderous writing* — Saturday Review

I know "pre" is the suffix originally from Latin meaning "before".

Does anyone how come adding "pre" adds the meaning of **something bad** to the word "presage" **etymologically?**

Other examples are "pretext" and "preclude" also taken from *The Vocabulary Builder* by Magoosh.

> **Pretext** *(n.)* A reason given for something that is not the actual reason
>
> **Preclude** *(v.)* to make it impossible for something to happen
>
> **Presentiment** *(n.)* A feeling that something (typically bad) is about to happen

---

Thank you for answer anyhow. But are you sure *pre* and *per* are the **same**? (It says, "extended").

**Pre**

[image]

So if "beyond" **extends**, it means, **too much**. Wouldn't *too much* mean *too less*?

Comment: I would like to ask about the words "presentiment" and "sentiment" too. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's "gotcha"...

Comment: @Mari-LouA Gotcha. Thanks too haha.

Comment: On second thoughts, it's "got it". Gotcha is normally negative, it means I have caught you in the act of doing something wrong.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I used the abbreviation of "got it" as "gotta". And you lead me to wrong way? Come on Italian sweet.

Comment: No, gotta is wrong. Gotta is short for **I have got to (must) + verb** as in “I gotta go now.” P.S. Please don't call me Italian sweet

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ah sorry, I read somewhere that you've been living in Italy for a long time. Sorry. I apologize. Anyhow, got it!

Comment: It's the "sweet" bit, I dislike. I am Italian, there's nothing wrong with calling me Italian.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry anyhow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the main sense conveyed by the prefix [pre-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pre-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) is that of anticipating in time or space.

> word-forming element meaning "before," from Old French pre- and Medieval Latin pre-, both from Latin prae (adverb and preposition) ***"before in time or place,"...extended form of root *[per-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*per-?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_52721)  "forward," hence "beyond, in front of, before."***

(Etymonline)

Non negative examples:

> Predict, prevent, prepare, prelude, presume etc.

Comment: But per- is a different prefix from pre-.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder about **pre** right from the time I have bought a very very very very very very very very very good book.

Comment: So how come does the relationship with the suffix "per" could connote the negative nuance?

Comment: @KentaroTomono - the negative, neutral  or positive connotation of term starting with President pre is just incidental. ***Pre- as a suffix doesn’t convey a negative sense!***

Comment: Doesn't the word "prevent" convey the negative meaning? "To **prevent** someone something from doing / going etc something"

Comment: @KentaroTomono - look at the terms I listed.,do they sound negative to you??? And there are more..

Comment: You are talking about the **extended** suffix of **per**. Would you elaborate using "presage and "sage" example please?

Comment: @KentaroTomono -  ***presage:*** late 14c., "something that portends," from Latin praesagium "a foreboding," from praesagire "to perceive beforehand, forebode," from praesagus (adj.) "perceiving beforehand, prophetic," ***from prae "before" (see pre-) + sagus "prophetic,"***.

Comment: How come on the earth does "to perceive beforehand" connote negative nature??

Comment: @KentaroTomono - that’s going to be a POB issue. To your main question the answer is “***NO***”.

Comment: Even if I give you another examples "pretentious", "precedented" ( as the word unprecedented conveys **positive** meanings?? )

Comment: "To perceive beforehand" does **not** connote anything negative. It just happens that  _some_ words beginning with 'pre', meaning before, happen to have acquired a negative connotation.

Answer (score 2):

The prefix **pre-** just means “before” (in time, place, order, degree, or importance) [Oxford Dictionaries]

- If someone ***predicts*** a candidate's victory they either have a *good* or *bad* ***presentiment*** *(n)*, in which case they might ***prewarn*** the press and the public.
- Dams are built in order to ***prevent*** rivers, inland lakes, and seas from flooding towns and valleys.
- Something that is ***prehistoric*** probably dates back thousands of years but it could also refer sarcastically to last year's iPhone.
- A ***precocious*** child whose parents are talented musicians, renowned doctors, scientists etc. is said to be ***predestined*** for great things.
- ***President*** Barack Obama won the Nobel Peace Prize, a highly ***prestigious*** award

All of the words in bold contain the prefix *pre-*, none carry negative connotations.

The word ***predilection*** literally means “liking before”, to *prefer* something above all the rest, i.e. to have a favourite. The word is derived from Medieval Latin *praediligere* to love more. A person who strongly likes fast cars will probably have a [predilection for](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predilection#synonym-discussion) expensive vehicles.

### The etymology of ‘sage’

***[Sage](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sage#Etymology_1)*** is a Middle English word, derived from Old French *sage* (11th century), from Vulgar Latin *sapius* and *sapere*, from ancient Greek  σαφής, *saphês*, (clear). In Latin, *sapere* was to have a taste or flavour of (*sapore*), later it was used as a metaphor for something that was evident (strong tasting?). In Oscan (an extinct language from Southern Italy, 500 BC to AD 100) the term ***sipus***, which is translated as  *sciens* (knowing, understanding) in Latin, is believed by some scholars to signify **“having known”**.  Therefore, the literal translation of *presage* would be "pre-taste" to taste (*see*, *understand*, *know*) something beforehand.

Admittedly, the OP's **[presage](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presage#examples)** does carry a negative connotation…

> I had a nagging presage that the results of my medical tests would not be good.

but not always,

> The sight of the first robin is always a welcome presage of spring

<sub>(Examples: *Merriam-Webster*)</sub>

---

Further reading

[Dizionario Etimilogico Online](https://www.etimo.it/?term=sapere) (in Italian)
[Oscan language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscan_language) (Wikipedia)
Italic and Romance: Linguistic studies in honor of Ernst Pulgram ([link](https://books.google.it/books?id=hV5AAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&dq=sipus%20oscan&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis17Kuk_ffAhV4HrkGHaLtClIQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=sipus%20oscan&f=false))

Answer (score 0):

According to dictionary.com, pre means

> akin to first, fore-, prior, pro

For instance pre-school. It's before school. Prestigious has a positive connotation, and predict doesn't have a negative or positive connotation. Here are some more examples:

## Predisposed

> "Solutions of uranyl salts (nitrate, &c.) behave to reagents as follows: sulphuretted hydrogen produces green uranous salt with **precipitation** of sulphur; sulphide of ammonium in neutral solutions gives a black precipitate of UO 2 S, which settles slowly and, while being washed in the filter, breaks up partially into hydrated UO 2 an sulphur; ammonia gives a yellow precipitate of uranate of ammonia, characteristically soluble in hot carbonate of ammonia solution; prussiate of potash gives a brown precipitate which in appearance is not unlike the precipitate produced by the same reagent in cupric salts."

## Preoccupied

> "I know you've been **preoccupied**, but everyone else has noticed his interest in you."

## Prestigious

> "The cardiology team at Ealing Hospital has been awarded the
>   **prestigious** accolade of Cardiology Team of the Year 2013 by Hospital
>   Doctor Magazine."

All examples taken from sentence.yourdictionary.com.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Let me read yours carefully later a bit.(m_m).